# Autohotkey - toggle keys

Tags: autohotkey

I want to achieve this

1. press "a" > output "a"
2. press "a" again > output "b"
3. press "a" again > output "a"
4. press "a" again > output "b"
5. keep repeating these...

Below script does what I want, but with little issue.
When I press and hold "a", it output "abababab"......
But I need it to act like keep outputing the current character until I release the key and activate the toggling.

i.e. press and hold "a" > output "aaaaaaaa"... > release "a" > stop outputing and toggle to "b"

Anyone know how can I achieve that? Thanks in advance!

```
Toggle:=0
$a::
Toggle:=!Toggle
if(Toggle=1) {
    send, a
} else {
    send, b
}
return
```

Comment: I'm not an AHK expert but there has to be a feature in it to detect when a key is pressed and then released. Try searching their help for those terms, or "key down" and "key up".

Answer (score 0):

This script should do the task. Note that when in the mode of replacing
`a` by `b` (meaning the second `a`),
a repeating press on `a` will repeat the `b`.

```
toggle:=0
apressed:=0
a::
    apressed:=1
    if (toggle=0) {
        send, a
    } else {
        send, b
    }
    return

a up::
    apressed:=0
    toggle:=!toggle
    return
```